# Is it possible to only send one variable from a struct if that struct exists as an array?

Tags: c, struct

I apologise if this seems simple, I'm still learning and I'm new to C.

I have this as my struct:

```
struct Game{
   char id;
   char name[50];
   char genre[20];
   char platform[15];
   char company[30];
   float price;
   int quantity = 10; 
};
```

And this declared as a struct array:

```
struct Game gList[30];
```

I have a function where I'm passing all of 'gList' to search through values in the gList[i].name variables.

So my question is, **is it possible to send only the gList[i].name part of the struct to the function as a parameter?(ie All the 30 *name* values only).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you could make an array of pointers that point to the `name` field and pass it to the function:

```
char* ptr[30];
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    ptr[i] = gList[i].name;

func(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. However, you can pass iterators to functions just fine. Typical pattern:

```
struct context { struct Game *gList; int nList; int i; }
char *iter_names(void *baton)
{
    struct context *ptr = baton;
    if (ptr->i == ptr->nList) return NULL;
    return ptr->gList[ptr->i++].name;
}


void wants_name_array(char (*nextname)(void *), void *baton)
{
    while (char *name = nextname(baton))
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        /* and whatever else you are doing */
    }
}

/* ... */
    struct context baton = { gList, 30, 0 };
    wants_name_array(iter_names, baton);
```

Yeah it looks kinda bad. Thankfully, `gcc` has an extension that makes this much better.

```
void wants_name_array(char (*nextname)())
{
    while (char *name = nextname())
    {
        printf("%s\n", name);
        /* and whatever else you are doing */
    }
}

/* ... */
{
     int i = 0;
     char *nextname()
     {
         if (i == 30) return NULL;
         return gList[i++].name;
     }
     wants_name_array(nextname);
}
```

When using this particular `gcc` extension, never ever return nested functions. Undefined behavior.